# Jquery ui autocomplete. Search label and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like:

```
data = [
  { label:'name', value:'val', id: ... },
  {},
  ...
]
```

How do I add an item to the autocompletion when I enter 'val'? Currently this only searches labels.

```
source: function (request, response) {
  response($.map(data, function (item) {
    if (item.label.indexOf($(".city-list").val()) + 1 > 0 ||       
        item.value.indexOf($(".city-list").val()) + 1 > 0) {
      return {
        label: item.label,
        value: item.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: There is no way to do this by jqueryui/autocomplete. Instead, you have to override the select event, and update the input value manually.

Comment: any reason you + 1 and then compare to `> 0`?  why not just compare to `> -1`?